# Do I need to store the Firebase url in a server side secure location? or does the Firebase security cover this?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm basically asking, should I store the Firebase url in the client side e.g. the browser?

Hackers can then easily take that. But if my security in Firebase is good enough, should it be okay to store it client side?

Answer (score 1):

The URL is your interface with the Firebase Realtime Database, it is okay to expose it publicly as long as you have proper security rules.

If a malicious user gets ahold of the URL and tries to delete or save data, your security rules will keep them at bay.

Comment: Thank you. Can you add on here what some of those security rules would be, examples of the most important ones

Comment: It's completely dependent on your data structure. If you have user specific data I recommend giving the user security section a read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-integrate-auth.